# future get is terminating the program

Tags: c++, qt, c++11

I'm running the process asynchronously using `QEvent`, after my process completes I'm just setting promise and trying to get it using future get function.

However it is not working asynchronously, it's working synchronously.

May I know what wrong I am doing?

**code:**

```
Win::Win(QObject *parent) :
    MyCustomWidget(parent)
{
    qDebug()<<execute().get();

}
std::future<int> Win::execute()
{
    auto promise = std::make_shared<std::promise<int>>();
    auto temp = [=]
    {
        ///process
        qDebug()<<"done";
        promise->set_value(100);

    };

    QApplication::postEvent(this,new MyCustomEvent(temp));
    ////QApplication::processEvents()  without this line its not working may know the reason
   //// But without this line and without future get also its working
    return promise->get_future();
}
```

Comment: It seems to me that you run `execute()` in the main thread. Try to use asynchronous run by [QtConcurrent::run()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtconcurrentrun.html). You can use the `QFuture` and `QFutureWatcher` classes to monitor the status of the function. I also recommend not to mix using Qt and STL

Comment: upd: from [std::future::get](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/get) documentation: "The get method **waits until the future has a valid result** and (depending on which template is used) retrieves it. It effectively calls wait() in order to wait for the result." So, `get()` is synchronous, blocking method. You need to use `std::async()` or `QtConcurrent::run()`.

Comment: @VladimirBershov But why its crashing instead of wait.

Comment: have you run it in a debugger?

Comment: @kfstone I just updated the code, i found the issue but i am not sure what is the use of processevent

Comment: @Jeggu does the behaviour stay the same, when you acquire the future before posting the event (e.g by storing it in a variable)? Using a promise in different contexts (which seems to be the case here) result in undefined behaviour as described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42534367/is-stdpromiset-thread-safe