# Is std::promise<T> thread-safe?

Tags: c++, c++11, asynchronous, promise

Is it safe, like in the case of `std::mutex` for a `std::promise<T>` to be made `mutable`, or does it depend on `T`? As in:

```
using Data = std::tuple<bool, int, int>;

struct X {

    std::future<Data> prepare() const {
        return m_promise.get_future();
    }

    void asyncHandler(int a, int b) const {
        m_promise.set_value({true, a, b});
    }

    void cancel() const {
        m_promise.set_value({false, 0, 0});
    }

    mutable std::promise<Data> m_promise;  // Is this safe?
};


void performAsyncOp(const X& x) {
     std::future<Data> fut = x.prepare();
     dispatch(x);
     std::future_status result = fut.wait_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(150));
     if (result == std::future_status::timeout) {
         x.cancel();
     }

     handleResult(fut.get());
}
```

Comment: It turns out this pattern is broken anyway due to futures not being resettable. I'd have thought that future.get() would have reset it but it doesn't. I'm struggling to see the point of all this promise/future stuff really.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's have a detailed look at the API:

```
// retrieving the result
future<R> get_future();

// setting the result
void set_value(see below);
void set_exception(exception_ptr p);

// setting the result with deferred notification
void set_value_at_thread_exit(see below);
void set_exception_at_thread_exit(exception_ptr p);
```

None of the methods is marked `const`, so we can't infer any knowledge about the constness from just this. However, the standard mandates thread-safety on the following methods (c.f. [33.6.6.2](http://eel.is/c++draft/futures.promise#15)): `set_­value`, `set_­exception`, `set_­value_­at_­thread_­exit`, and `set_­exception_­at_­thread_­exit`.

This leaves `get_future` unspecified with respect to thread-safety. However, `get_future` throws an exception if called more than once, c.f. [33.6.6.14.1](http://eel.is/c++draft/futures.promise#14.1). So calling `get_future` from multiple threads doesn't really make sense from a practical point of view.

There is no guarantee for thread-safety when calling `get_future` and any of the `set` methods and `get_future` (no matter if it will throw or not) simultaneously, as far as I can see.